# What are the other examples of compounds undergoing decarboxylation in the pericylic manner as shown by β-ketocarboxylic acids?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carboxylic-acids

I know that β-ketocarboxylic acids undergo decarboxylation on light heating through an enol intermediate undergoing a pericyclic reaction. However, what other groups may be placed at the β position that may give the same decarboxylation reaction?

I haven't been able to find any reputable sources. However, my teacher gave us a question in which an imine at β position underwent decarboxylation following the same process as a β-ketocarboxylic acid would. Does this reaction happen and are there other groups that follow the exact decarboxylation mechanism when at the β position?